# Beautiful Soup returning "[]"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, findall

I'm attempting to pull the company information off the bloomberg company profile website using the below code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/AAPL:US'

source = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')

company_name = soup.findAll('h1', class_= 'companyName__9bd88132')

company_description = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'description__ce057c5c')

print(company_name)
print(company_description)
```

But I am only getting two "[ ]" back as a result. In the responses I've seen to similar questions, they have said its because the incorrect divs are being pulled, but I don't think that is the case here. Would someone know why it isn't working?
Edit: I've attached the section of html I am trying to pull from below:

```
<section class="companyProfileOverview__aa874298 up__e13cf193"><section class="info__d075c560"><h1 class="companyName__9bd88132">Apple Inc</h1><div class="description__ce057c5c">Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets personal computers and related personal computing and mobile communication devices along with a variety of related software, services, peripherals, and networking solutions. Apple sells its products worldwide through its online stores, its retail stores, its direct sales force, third-party wholesalers, and resellers.</div></section><section class="currentPriceContainer"><p class="currentPriceLabel__f1524605">CURRENT PRICE</p><div><div class="inlineRow__7728fc34"><span class="tickerText__d2e1ee30">AAPL:US</span><span class="priceText__0feeaba3">343.99</span><span class="currency__bef924de">USD</span></div><span class="triangle__73a7d8b2 up__a3b61807"></span><div class="inlineRow__7728fc34"><span class="priceChange__5e691975">+10.53</span><span class="percentChange__3c14f7c4">+3.16%</span></div><div class="time__245ca7bb "><span>As of 08:00 PM EDT 06/09/2020 </span></div><a class="quoteLink__d3ac120b" href="/quote/AAPL:US">SEE QUOTE</a></div></section><div class="infoTable__96162ad6"><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">SECTOR</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">Technology</div></section><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">INDUSTRY</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">Hardware</div></section><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">SUB-INDUSTRY</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">Communications Equipment</div></section><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">FOUNDED</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">01/03/1977</div></section><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">ADDRESS</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">1 Infinite Loop
Cupertino, CA 95014
United States</div></section><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">PHONE</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">1-408-996-1010</div></section><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">WEBSITE</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">www.apple.com</div></section><section class="infoTableItem__1003ce53"><h2 class="infoTableItemLabel__c9a5d511">NO. OF EMPLOYEES</h2><div class="infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb">100000</div></section></div></section>
```

I am trying to pull the company name(companyName__9bd88132) and the company description(description__ce057c5c). Eventually I would like to pull the sector information as well.

Comment: first you should check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add elements because `requests`  and `BS` can't run JavaScript. Second you should check `print(source.text)` to see what you get from server - and here I see `<title>Bloomberg - Are you a robot?</title>`  which means that server recognized script and sent different content. Now it may need more work - ie. headers like `User-Agent` - to behave like real person and maybe then server send correct data. OR you may need Selenium to control real web browser which will behave more like real person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/AAPL:US'
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
ua=UserAgent()
hdr = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
source = requests.get(URL,headers=hdr)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, features="html.parser")
# print(soup)
company_name = soup.find_all('h1', class_= 'companyName__9bd88132')

company_description = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'description__ce057c5c')

print(company_name)
print(company_description)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code! It initially didn't work, but i had to change "ua=UserAgent()" to "ua=UserAgent(verify_ssl=False)" because there was a problem verifying the ssl. Thanks again.